# How to prove that, If X is not empty, then "set of all functions from X to the empty set" is empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is an exercise at the end of section 8 of Halmos- Naive set theory.
So the first part of the exercise asks us to prove that "set of all functions from $\phi$ to Y or $Y^\phi$", has exactly one element namely $\phi$, whether Y is empty or not.
After proving this, we have two results, which are-
$\phi^\phi$ = {$\phi$} and $Y^\phi$ = {$\phi$}, respectively for the conditions on Y.
Now the second part asks us to prove the following-
"If X is not empty, then $\phi^X$ is empty"
The first thing that I did after reading this part was I changed the question to this-
"If X is empty, then $\phi^X$ is not empty"
This was my first assumption because I read something like "if you want to prove something is true, prove that it can never be false" in the book itself.
While ignoring the word "never" I chose to make this assumption anyway.

And the statement "If X is empty, then $\phi^X$ is not empty" is already true from part 1. ( because, $\phi^\phi$ = {$\phi$})

Hence $\phi^X$ = $\phi$, where X is not empty.
There are two problems with this approach. 
First I don't even know whether this is the right way of doing this. 
Second even if it is, this method is unsatisfactory.

All I know from part 2 is that "If X is not empty, then set of all functions from X to $\phi$" is empty, which means there are no functions from X to $\phi$.

This thing has been bothering me from past two days, any response will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Part of the definition of a function is that every element of $X$ (the domain) is a assigned a unique element of the codomain (the range). If the codomain is empty (which it is, in your case), such elements cannot be assigned, so such functions cannot exist.

Comment: I suspect you are overthinking this.  Check the definition of a function.  Ask yourself if we can construct a function from a nonempty set to an empty set.

Comment: Thanks for the response @MichaelMorrow. It was always about the definition of a function :)

Comment: Thanks for the response @hardmath. Yes according to the definition of a function, there is no problem in constructing a function from an empty set to non-empty set, since I guess the concept of "vacuous truth" comes into play. But when it comes to constructing a set from a non-empty set to empty set, then it violates the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using set theory a function from $X$ to $Y$ is defined as a functional and serial binary relation in $X \times Y$, that is, a subset $R\subset X \times Y$ with the following two properties:

1. (seriality) For every $x\in X$ there is some $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$.
2. (functionality) If $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ belongs to $R$ then $y=z$.

Now observe that if $Y=\emptyset $ then $X\times Y=\emptyset $ and the unique subset of the empty set is the empty set itself so, if any, a function must be represented by the empty set, however in this case the seriality condition will fail. Then we conclude that $Y^X$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed response. Helped a lot. Have a nice day :)